# "Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. ..."?

Tags: ios, ios11, passkit

My app under iOS 11 is logging:

```
Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or file a Radar.
```

Haven't seen that before. Does anyone have an idea where this comes from?

(My app uses low level keychain methods not PassKit. But HockeyApp seems to.)

Comment: I have the same issue, but so far it occured only on a IPhone X. Other Phones with IOS 11 work fine.

Comment: In what context do you see this? I'm seeing it when I tap on a mailto link in a WKWebView.

Comment: The same message end app freezes when performing presentViewController for [CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:] device iPhone7; OS:12.1.4; no SIM; device has lock with pin (no fingerprint). CNContactStore has CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized permission

Answer (score 0):

I am getting same error, and i fixed by using below code

```
let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
vc.delegate = self
let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            present(navigationController, animated: false) {
                print("Present")
            }
```